# Deserialize, Copy and Merge Orders from XML to C#

Tags: c#, xml

Here's the flow,

- Load XML file
- Deserialize to list in c#
- Map xml object to c# list
- Merge orders but increment order's product count

  ```
  public Order[] Load(string path)
  {
      var element = XElement.Load(path);
      var orders = new List<XElement>();
      orders = element.Elements();

      var _orders = new List<Order>();
      var _alreadyAddedOrders = new List<string>();
      foreach (var order in orders)
      {
          var orderTemp = new Order();
          orderTemp.OrderDate = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("date").ToString());
          orderTemp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("id").ToString());
          orderTemp.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("categoryId").ToString());
          orderTemp.ProductCount = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("productCount").ToString());

          foreach (var secondOrder in _orders)
          {
              var orderMatches = (orderTemp.OrderDate == secondOrder.OrderDate && 
                                  orderTemp.Id == secondOrder.Id && 
                                  orderTemp.CategoryId == secondOrder.CategoryId);
              if (orderMatches)
              {
                  orderTemp.ProductCount += secondOrder.ProductCount;
                  _alreadyAddedOrders.Add(secondOrder.OrderDate.ToString() + secondOrder.Id.ToString() + secondOrder.CategoryId.ToString());
              }
          }

          if(!_alreadyAddedOrders.Contains(orderTemp.OrderDate.ToString() + orderTemp.Id.ToString() + orderTemp.CategoryId.ToString()))
              _orders.Add(orderTemp);
      }

      return _orders.ToArray();
  }

  public class Order
  {
      public int Id;
      public int CategoryId;
      public int OrderDate;
      public int ProductCount;
  }
  ```

and XML is like this, more then 20,000 rows,

```
<orders>
    <order date='2000-04-20' Id='1' categoryId='100' productCount='3' />
    <order date='2000-06-21' Id='2' categoryId='101' productCount='14' />
</orders>
```

Note : Order ID is not unique, date + id + category, is unique altogether

Comment: @Mathematics: This code is still not working. All the `Convert`-statements are invalid and the conversion of the date should be to `DateTime`. Please make sure, that you post tested code, that produce the expected result.

Comment: @HenrikHansen the `Order` class (*at the end of the code block*) stores the date as an Integer.  you should take another look at the code that has been posted, it looks fully functional to me.

Comment: @Malachi: Yes I can see that, but the date-attribute in the xml-file is not in a valid integer format but in a date time format. I'm just trying to find some consistency :-)

Comment: I see what you are saying, @HenrikHansen, you are very correct.  ***Mathematics***, have you tested this code to make sure that it works?  is the XML that you have provided in the right format?

Comment: @Malachi I am sorry, this happened as I was trying to do a refactor at same time as well, I fixed it now. thank you

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I made sure my code changes won't in-validate existing answers, it had already been pointed out in answers, thanks

Comment: @HenrikHansen answer actually addresses that very issue, in the future please make sure to post your most current working code.  if you have errors in your code your question could be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement doesn't work:

> `orderTemp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("id").ToString());`

It should be

```
orderTemp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("id").Value);
```

---

The `Order.OrderDate` should be of type `DateTime` in order to meet the format of the `date`-attribute in the xml-file

> `date='2000-04-20'`

---

If you modify the `Order` class to:

```
  public class Order
  {
    public int Id;
    public int CategoryId;
    public DateTime OrderDate;
    public int ProductCount;

    public string GroupId => $"{OrderDate}{Id}{CategoryId}";

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"{Id} -> {CategoryId} -> {OrderDate} -> {ProductCount}";
    }

    public static Order FromXml(XElement xElement, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
      if (xElement == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(xElement));

      return new Order
      {
        OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(xElement.Attribute("date").Value, formatProvider),
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Attribute("id").Value),
        CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Attribute("categoryId").Value),
        ProductCount = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Attribute("productCount").Value)
      };
    }

  }
```

Then you can handle the xml-input like:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> Load(string path, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
  var xElements = XElement.Load(path);
  var xOrders = xElements.Elements();

  formatProvider = formatProvider ?? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

  var groups = xOrders.Select(xo => Order.FromXml(xo, formatProvider)).GroupBy(o => o.GroupId);

  foreach (var group in groups)
  {
    Order order = group.First();
    order.ProductCount = group.Sum(o => o.ProductCount);
    yield return order;
  }
}
```

---

An alternative method to read the xml-file is to use `XmlSerializer.Deserialize(...)`

Comment: +1, Very nice. I wonder what is the complexity (Big O) of the `GroupBy`. It could be O(n log n), making this optimal solution (reducing it from original O(n^2) without even using the `Dictionary` that could be inside the `GroupBy`).

Answer (score 5):

### Naming

```
var orders = new List<XElement>();
var _orders = new List<Order>();
```

First, according to the C# naming convention, you should never have underscores in your variable names declared inside methods. Second, this is pretty confusing.

How about :

```
var xmlOrders = new List<XElement>();
var convertedOrders = new List<Order>();
```

It's a weird (and probably controversial) thing to say, but naming has to be one of the hardest thing to do when it comes to programming. You want your name to be so clear that anyone reading your code would be able to understand it quickly. So names need to be clear and exact.

For example : `secondOrder` isn't a second order, so it's confusing.

What is it, how should it be named? Well it seems like this `order` is an `alreadyAddedOrder`. You might want to find another name, but it should give the same "vibe".

### C# things

1. You can use the *object initializer* :

   var orderTemp = new Order();
   orderTemp.OrderDate = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("date").ToString());
   orderTemp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("id").ToString());
   orderTemp.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("categoryId").ToString());
   orderTemp.ProductCount = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("productCount").ToString());

becomes :

```
var orderTemp = new Order
{
    OrderDate = Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("date").ToString()),
    Convert.ToInt32(order.Attribute("id").ToString()),
    //etc..
};
```

It's simply shorter and clearer, but it is compiled the same way as your previous code.

> 2. Note : Order ID is not unique, date + id + category, is unique altogether

We've got a great case of `override Equals`.

As it is right now, the responsibility of deciding if two orders are equal is stored (as code) in your `Load` method. Is this fine? I don't think so!

An `Order` should be able to tell if it's equal to another Order`.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id;
    public int CategoryId;
    public int OrderDate;
    public int ProductCount;

    public override Equals(object obj)
    {
       //etc.
    }
}
```

I recommend you read a little bit on how to correctly implement the `Equals` override as you'll also need to override the `GetHashCode` method.

3. Don't use `Convert.ToInt32` when you have a `string` that should be an `int`. Use `int.Parse`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199484/2785479)
4. Also, override `ToString` to replace `orderTemp.OrderDate.ToString() + orderTemp.Id.ToString() + orderTemp.CategoryId.ToString()`.

#### Encapsulation

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id;
    public int CategoryId;
    public int OrderDate;
    public int ProductCount;
}
```

Now, you might not feel it's necessary to implement this as it's a pretty "defensive programming" thing, but I feel it's important to talk about it. If I look at this class from a business point of view, it means that if I pass an order, I should be able to modify the said order afterwards. But when an order is passed, *should I* be able to modify, say, the `OrderDate`? Not really. There's also an important point that once you override the `GetHashCode` method, you should consider making your object "read only", so that it doesn't mess with the hashes.

`Order` becomes :

```
public class Order
{
    public Order(int id, int categoryId, int orderDate, int productCount)
    { 
        //etc.
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public int CategoryId { get; }
    public int OrderDate { get; }
    public int ProductCount { get; }

    //Equals and GetHashCode override.
}
```

### General points

- Don't use `_alreadyAddedOrders` to keep `string`. You're looking for orders, this list should contain orders.
- Why is `OrderDate` an `int`? If it's stored as milliseconds, it should be a `long`, otherwise I don't see how you can parse an `int` to a meaningful date.

Comment: The `Order` class could be a `readonly struct` and implement `IEquatable<Order>`. I would also put some docs on the `Id` property with a huge warning about this not being a unique identifier.

Comment: @BradM Or, you know, make sure it's unique. Because it should be.

Comment: @Mast If data's coming from an old legacy system there's not much you can do about it if you want to keep relation between the old and new system.

Comment: @IEatBagels Of-course, legacy systems get an exception on many rules. But I haven't seen anyone mentioning legacy systems. Did I miss a comment?

Comment: @IEatBagels I agree with your point here, this isn't something we could change and belongs to legacy system